# Adobe Reader/Acrobat in ISO 32000 mode?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, specifications, adobe-reader

We receive PDF files from all over the world. Some of them are way off-spec, but Adobe Reader opens them nicely. The problem is that we use several other systems with built-in PDF viewer controls (that actually adhere to ISO 32000) for displaying and working with these files. However, they fail to open files that are not according to specifications. The problem is that until Adobe Reader can display the files correctly, we have no way to bang the door at the PDF producer. Furthermore, we must have these files on archive for 25+ years and we need to ensure view-ability throughout this period. But we can't be sure that an off-spec file could be opened 25 years from now.

Is there a way to force Adobe Reader or Acrobat XI to ISO 32000 mode (if there's such), so that it will fail to open files that are not according to PDF specifications? This way we could have more luck asking off-spec PDF producers to fix their software.

**EDIT**

We are using a 3rd party WinForms user control in our application to display PDF files arriving from all over the world. Every once in a while we encounter a PDF file that opens with an error message. We then send the file to the 3rd party and they examine the problem. Most of the time they say that the PDF file is off spec. They then provide a fix because if Reader doesn't complain then they will gracefully swallow the error too. Last time we encountered such problem we got the response that the file contains a color specification that is strictly not correct according to the PDF specification. We usually test these files using PDF Tools' PDF Validator here: http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx before sending them out and the results from this tool correlate with the statements of the 3rd party.
I'm not an expert of the PDF standard, but I have some files that are rendered fine with Reader 11.0.2, but Reader 11.0.3 will just display boxes instead of text. This means that Adobe products are no exceptions from having problems with off-spec files.

Comment: *we have no way to bang the door at the PDF producer* - of course you have. That a PDF is shown as intended in (some version of) Adobe Reader does not mean anything concerning its correctness by the standard. Unfortunately there is no ultimate ISO 32000-1 conformance checker (yet) and ISO 32000-2 is on its way. Considering your archiving liabilities you should invest in a person (team?) checking questionable PDFs and rejecting them referencing the respective standards broken.

Comment: We don't have to have a team for that, the software takes care of it pretty good. The problem is the communications part. When you provide a service and face two big companies on both sides then things are not always black and white. If the "we've-done-it-like-this-for-ages" department of "big company A" issues a document in non-conforming PDF format that must be received, processed and signed by the "I-don't-give-a-hack-about-standards-just-make-it-work" department of "even bigger company B" while we are providing the bridge between them, then you simply have nowhere to go complaining.

Comment: It is probably better this way. If we had someone to bang the door at, then the next question would be "How do we fix it then?", and an endless mailing would start. And frankly, we do not want to dig knee deep in THEIR s..., without even knowing what PDF producer they use (usually these PDF producers even 'forget' to fill the PDF producer tag in the resulting file). You'd be surprised how many PDFs are not up to the specs according to the pdf-tools site I referenced in my OP. I'll have my people make some statistics about this.

Comment: http://duff-johnson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/PDFValidationDreamOrYawn.pdf
I do not know about the statistics in here, but most of his thoughts correlate with ours.

Comment: *The problem is the communications part* - that sounds bad. It actually sounds as if even a ISO 32000 mode as you asked for would not really help. I fortunately have always been in a better position as we were in a position which was assumed to be most competent in the matters at hand. That been said, what exactly do your agreements with the parties involved say? What kinds of documents have you promised to process? Is there some argumentation base in there?

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Reader has always tried to ensure that user's can open the PDFs that they receive, regardless of how "broken" they are.  Because the average user blames the viewer/reader and not the authoring tool.  We've tried to tighten things up over the years where we could - but it's never been w/o controversy.

That said, I am curious what types of things are in these PDFs that are "way off spec" and how you are detecting that?   As Max mentions, there is no publicly available PDF validation tools - there are some things that offer bits and pieces (such as the Check PDF Syntax features in Adobe Acrobat) but nothing comprehensive.

In the same vein, I'd love to know what tool you are using that claims to be "an ISO 320001- compliant viewer", because AFAIK they don't exist.

Leonard Rosenthol * 
PDF Architect *
Adobe Systems

Comment: Thank you for joining the discussion, Leonard. Please see my original, edited post for update.

Comment: @pdfsage Welcome on SO ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no "ISO 32000" compliance checking application out there. It is still kind of the understanding that if Adobe Reader can display it, it is OK. Of course, this is not really a good thing, but it is working. However, there are even differences between Adobe Reader versions, the older being more tolerant than the newer ones.

We can say that a well-behaved PDF viewer attempts to display as much as possible and if needed repairs the file (this is one of the reasons why Adobe Reader is rather big; it is set to deal with a lot of not so quite good files).

So, what to do… In any case follow the developments with ISO 32000 as well as the other PDF standards (such as PDF/X, PDF/A, PDF/UA etc.). In particular, if it is for long-term storage, one should follow PDF/A, and maybe even convert the file collection to PDF/A standards.

To the second question, I am not aware of a "strict ISO 32000 mode" with Acrobat or Reader.

Comment: I can agree on your observation that older versions were more tolerant.